# Why does npm start fail due to CORS error, but HOST=127.0.0.1 npm start succeed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, npm, cors

I am developing a simple application using Flask for the backend and React for the frontend. When I try to start my React application using npm start, I encounter a CORS error. However, when I use HOST=127.0.0.1 npm start, the application runs successfully without any CORS error.

Here is the code snippet for the Flask application:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from os import environ

try:
    origins = environ["ORIGINS"]
except KeyError:
    kwargs = {}
else:
    if "," in origins:
        origins = origins.split(",")
    kwargs = dict(resources={r"/*": dict(origins=origins)})

print(kwargs)

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, **kwargs)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "reached\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

Here is the code snippet for the React application:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const localhost = window.location.hostname

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = localhost
    fetch(`http://${localhost}:5000/`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((data) => setResponse(data))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>"reached" expected:</h2>
      <p>{response}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am using the hostname dynamically from window.location.hostname for the fetch URL. Does anyone know why specifying the host as 127.0.0.1 resolves the CORS error, while just using npm start does not?

Comment: I see the error on DevTool Console, that says "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy..."

Comment: I run `./app.py # with ORIGINS=...`

`1. ./app.py`
`2. ORIGINS='*' ./app.py`
`3. ORIGINS=http://localhost:3000,http://127.0.0.1:3000 ./app.py`
`4. ORIGINS=http://localhost ./app.py`
`5. ORIGINS=http://localhost:3000 ./app.py`

The CORS error always occurs in the "localhost" tab and the "127.0.0.1" tab in 4, 5.

Comment: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Doesn't look like your environment variable is being applied correctly. Please [edit] your question to show the exact command you're using to both define `ORIGINS` and launch your Flask app

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## I’ve Resolved It Myself

### Method of Investigation

With the help of ChatGPT, I created the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# clnt.py

import requests
from os import environ

LOCALHOST = environ.get("LOCALHOST", "127.0.0.1")

headers = {
    "Origin": f"http://{LOCALHOST}:3000",
}

response = requests.get(f"http://{LOCALHOST}:5000", headers=headers)

print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
print("Response Content:", response.content)
print("Response Headers:", response.headers)
```

I simplified the Flask program as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# serv.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "reached\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

Then, I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

./serv.py &
serv=$!
sleep 1
./clnt.py
LOCALHOST=localhost ./clnt.py
kill $serv
```

As a result, the above script output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2023 18:03:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Status Code: 200
Response Content: b'reached\n'
Response Headers: {'Server': 'Werkzeug/2.3.7 Python/3.9.6', 'Date': 'Tue, 26 Sep 2023 09:03:21 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '8', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://127.0.0.1:3000', 'Vary': 'Origin', 'Connection': 'close'}
Status Code: 403
Response Content: b''
Response Headers: {'Content-Length': '0', 'Server': 'AirTunes/695.5.1'}
```

It seems that the AirTunes server was using port 5000.

### Solution

I modified clnt.py and serv.py so that the port could be variable:

```
PORT=5001 ./serv.py &
serv=$!
sleep 1
PORT=5001 ./clnt.py
PORT=5001 LOCALHOST=localhost ./clnt.py
kill $serv
```

As a result, I obtained the expected output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2023 18:03:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Status Code: 200
Response Content: b'reached\n'
Response Headers: {'Server': 'Werkzeug/2.3.7 Python/3.9.6', 'Date': 'Tue, 26 Sep 2023 09:03:23 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '8', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://127.0.0.1:3000', 'Vary': 'Origin', 'Connection': 'close'}
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2023 18:03:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Status Code: 200
Response Content: b'reached\n'
Response Headers: {'Server': 'Werkzeug/2.3.7 Python/3.9.6', 'Date': 'Tue, 26 Sep 2023 09:03:23 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '8', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000', 'Vary': 'Origin', 'Connection': 'close'}
```

The front-end and back-end programs presented in the original question started working as expected after changing the port from 5000 to 5001 (provisionally).

Answer (score -1):

*'npm start'* will typically start your server on http://localhost:3000 instead of http://127.0.0.1:3000 unless you specify the host. Since your backend app runs on *HOST http://127.0.0.1*, which is a different host from http://localhost which the react app is running, the cors middleware is blocking the request. Cross-origin requests are subject to the same-origin policy, which restricts web pages from making requests to a different origin (host, protocol, or port) unless the server explicitly allows it using CORS headers.

In this case, you'd observe that all is well when you specify the host when starting the react app as *http://127.0.0.1* because the host is of same origin with that of the flask app and doesn't violate the CORS policy.

To resolve this you will have to modify your flask code to allow request from http://localhost origin, which will look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
    
app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "http://localhost"}}) #allow on same origin and http://localhost


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "reached\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

OR like this if you want to allow from all origins (any host)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
    
app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}}) #allow all origins


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "reached\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. Following your advice, I have made some modifications to the initial program. I have edited the original post to include those changes.

However, the situation remains unchanged.

I open two tabs by running `HOST=127.0.0.1 npm start & npm start &`.

I run `./app.py # with ORIGINS=...`

`./app.py`
`ORIGINS='*' ./app.py`
`ORIGINS=http://localhost:3000,http://127.0.0.1:3000 ./app.py`
`ORIGINS=http://localhost ./app.py`
`ORIGINS=http://localhost:3000 ./app.py`

The CORS error always occurs in the "localhost" tab and sometimes in the "127.0.0.1" tab.